# Swap positions of characters in a string

Tags: lua

I am looking for the easiest way to take a string, "ACB1 C123" and swap the positions of the space and the following character to "ACB1C 123".

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will probably cook up some cool regex gsub but until then you can use these very simple and ugly string modifications and continue what you're doing:

```
string = "ACB1 C123"
space = string:find(" ")
part = string:sub(space, space+1):gsub("(.)(.)", "%2%1")
newstring = string:sub(0, space-1) .. part .. string:sub(space+2)
print(newstring)
```

And if you don't like multiple lines here is an even uglier one liner ;)

```
string:sub(0, string:find(" ")-1) .. string:sub(string:find(" "), string:find(" ")+1):gsub("(.)(.)","%2%1") .. string:sub(string:find(" ")+2)
```

Comment: The fancy Lua pattern would simply be `('ACB1 C123'):gsub('(%s)(C)', '%2%1')`, but that _only_ works in the context of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the swap with captures:

```
s= "ACB1 C123"
print(s:gsub(" (.)","%1 "))
```

However, it does it for all occurrences of a space followed by a character.

To limit the swap to the first occurrence, use

```
print(s:gsub(" (.)","%1 ",1))
```

Comment: This gave me the output: "ACB1C 123 1", where is the ending 1 coming from?

Comment: @user1440188, `sub` returns the number of replacement made. If you so `s = s:gsub(" (.)","%1 ")`, this number will be discarded.

Comment: symbol= "ZZZ6C 2105"

new_s = symbol:gsub(" (.)"," %1")

return new_s

> ZZZ6C 2105

Still must be translating wrong

Comment: @user1440188, the code above works for  `ZZZ6C 2105` and gives `ZZZ6C2 105`.